# AWS Beanstalk ELB Logging Terraform - elb_account_id hardcoded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-elb

I am trying to enable logging on the load balancers created by AWS Beanstalk using Terraform, by referring the below article,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-access-logs.html

The article speaks about hard coding the 'elb-account-id' in the S3 policy so that the ELB has access to write logs to the bucket. Is this secure from a security standpoint, and what is this account ID?

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::elb-account-id:root"
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/prefix/AWSLogs/your-aws-account-id/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to replace this elb-account-id with my own account id?